# Wired NFC tag that is dynamic and programmable

Tags: raspberry-pi, smart-device, nfc, programmable

I'd like to send files from a computer (via my software) to an NFC tag (that can be read by an iPhone, similar to Apple Pay), but also be able to overwrite that same tag with another file on demand. Having a wired connection between the computer and NFC tag seems most practical, though I'm not sure of alternatives.

Which hardware acts as an NFC tag that can be dynamically programmed?

I thought about purchasing a plain Jane NFC reader off of eBay, but I'm not sure if readers themselves can act as tags programmable through an API in the system it's wired to. Would this work? If so, how can I assess a certain NFC reader for its integrability?

Comment: +1 I have the same question. @Gnumbertester did you find a solution for your question? Would you mind sharing it. Appreciate it.